# Linux : Creating a simple non-blocking server and client to communicate over named pipes

Tags: c, linux, named-pipes

I am trying to create a simple example of named pipes (FIFO). Here, the server will listen for message from the client, which writes on the named pipe, common to both of them. The special thing to be implemented is that the FIFO  should be non-blocking (usage of `O_NONBLOCK`).

By non blocking, I mean that the writer should return immediately after writing, if there is no reader. Similarly, reader should return immediately if there is no message(no writer).

I have created the blocking version though and its working fine. I am then trying to convert it to non-blocking.

Here's the client :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#define FIFO "/tmp/myFIFO"

/*
    This acts as the client, writing to the FIFO
 */

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *fp;
    int fifo_fd;

    if(argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage : ./fifo_client <message> \n");
        exit(1);
    }

    fifo_fd = open(FIFO, O_WRONLY | O_NONBLOCK);
    if(fifo_fd < 0)
    {
        perror("Error while open call");
        exit(1);
    }
    fp = fdopen(fifo_fd, "w");
    if(fp == NULL)
    {
        perror("Error while opening fd");
        exit(1);
    }

    fputs(argv[1],fp);

    /* Close the fp */
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Here's the server :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#define FIFO "/tmp/myFIFO"

/*
    This acts as a server waiting for strings to be written by the client, over the FIFO
 */

int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    int fifo_fd;
    char buf[1024];

    /* Create a FIFO */
    umask(0);
    if(mkfifo(FIFO,0666) < 0) /* 0666 is read and write permission*/
    {
        perror("Error creating FIFO");
        exit(1);
    }


    while(1) /*endless wait, keep reading strings and print*/
    {
        fifo_fd = open(FIFO, O_RDONLY | O_NONBLOCK);
        if(fifo_fd < 0)
        {
            perror("Error while open call");
            exit(1);
        }
        fp = fdopen(fifo_fd, "w");
        if(fp == NULL)
        {
            perror("Error while opening fd");
            exit(1);
        }

        if(!fgets(buf,1024,fp))
            printf("Nothing to read\n");
        else
            printf("Message Recieved : %s\n", buf);
    fclose(fp);
    sleep(1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I run the server first.

Secondly, on second terminal, when I run the client, I get the error :

```
Error while open call: No such device or address
```

What am I missing? I did `man`, and the parameters seem to be correct.

**EDIT**

Moving the `open` and `close` calls out of the while loop, did the job. But now if the client is started without starting the server, throws the following error :

Error while open call: No such device or address

The file `/tmp/myFIFO` exists on file-system from previous execution of the server, must be used by the client.

Comment: (comment unrelated to your issues).  If invoking the program with no arguments to get a usage statement is not an error, you should `exit 0`.  If it is an error, you should print the usage statement to stderr.  And `perror(FIFO)` is more useful than `perror("Error creating FIFO")` ; the user wants to see the name of the file in the error message.

Comment: You are not checking for errors returned by fgets and fputs, which means you don't care whether they succeed or not. Why complain about your program not working then?

Comment: That your server is printing repeatedly shows that it is *not* blocking.  You're not getting a prompt back because the server is not finished.

Comment: Is your client giving you that error while the server is running?  ie, does the fifo `/tmp/myFIFO` exist when the client gives that error?

Comment: @WilliamPursell : Yes server is running constantly printing `Nothing to read`. In fact I tried `echo Hello > /tmp/myFIFO`, it crashes the terminal.The permissions are also OK though, `prw-rw-rw-`

Comment: "it crashes the terminal". Hard to believe. What are you seeing exactly?

Comment: In the server, the "open" system call is inside the while loop but there is no corresponding close system call. Also fdopen is opening for write, while open is for read.

Comment: @kjohri `fclose` will call `close` on the underlying fd.

Comment: Please see the EDIT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is opening and closing the file in a loop. This makes no sense. There is a very short time interval between opening and closing, and your client must hit it. It has little chance to do so. The  "No such device or address" message happens exactly because the client misses the instant when the file is open. This is the main problem. Try moving `open`, `fopen` and `fclose` out of the server loop.

You also `open`ing for reading but `fopen`ing for writing, but I suppose it's just a typo. This combination will not run. You need to change the mode of `fopen` to `"r"`.

There are other, smaller issues.

1. You are not checking errors in the client. In your program the client will fail to `open` most of thee time, but sometimes open will succeed and write will fail.
2. It makes little sense to use `stdio` for the pipe in this program. `read` and `write` would do just fine.

Last but not least, `sleep` is an indication of a design issue. Indeed, in this program blocking I/O would make more sense. It's OK to use `sleep` if you just want to experiment with non-blocking I/O, but in real programs it should be avoided.

Comment: `You also opening for reading but fopening for writing, but I suppose it's just a typo.`. No, I did it intentionally, unknowing the fact that the combination won't work. Why is it so? Can you please provide the reason.?

Comment: Just moving the `open` and `close` calls out of the `while` loop did the job. The combo of `open` and `fopen` has no problem. But I didn't get, why putting the `open` and `close` calls inside the loop is creating the problem? The file is already created... So the second process, should be able to open it and write anytime. Is it something related to read-write locks?

Comment: @InsaneCoder this is how non-blocking FIFOs specified to work. The file must be open for reading, otherwise opening for writing will fail. With blocking IO it will just block.